# Installing Wordpress on LAMP server but Using a Directory on Windows Server

Tags: wordpress, dns, server, iis, lamp

The main site is running on a windows server. I want to install and run wordpress from a LINUX box at the following Directory.

example.com/blog/

What is the most suitable method to make this work? Can I create a directory that points to an IP address in the DNS?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off creating a sub-domain e.g. `blog.example.com` and pointing the `A-Records`(`AAAA-Records` for IPV6 addresses) for that sub-domain to the secondary server.

Your hosting company's support site should be able to to tell you how to accomplish this, but if you can tell us the name of your host, or if you have access to cPanel or Plesk we might be able to provide a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install samba https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/serverguide/C/samba-fileserver.html, share your windows folder as usual, then mount the folder to your linux box using samba. Then you'll be able to use the linux style file path to the mounted folder which is on your windows machine storing the files.